# Problema al querer relacionar dos tablas desde asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**Tengo este modelo:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebEscuelas.Models
{
    public class Estudiante
    {
        [Key]
        public int estudianteId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Primer Nombre")]
        public string primerNombre { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Display(Name = "Segundo Nombre")]
        public string segundoNombre { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Primer Apellido")]
        public string primerApellido { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Display(Name = "Segundo Apellido")]
        public string segundoApellido { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Fecha de Nacimiento")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime fechaNacimiento { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Dirección de Domicilio")]
        public string direccionDomicilio { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Display(Name = "Télefono")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{8})$", ErrorMessage = "Teléfono Inválido")]
        public int telefono { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**este es el controlador:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebEscuelas.Data;
using WebEscuelas.Models;

namespace WebEscuelas.Controllers
{
    public class EstudianteController : Controller
    {
        private readonly EscuelaContext _db;

        public EstudianteController(EscuelaContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Estudiante> lista = _db.Estudiante;

            return View(lista);
        }

        //Get
        public IActionResult Crear()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Crear(Estudiante estudiante)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Convertir a mayúsculas antes de actualizar
                estudiante.primerNombre = estudiante.primerNombre.ToUpper();
                estudiante.segundoNombre = estudiante.segundoNombre.ToUpper();
                estudiante.primerApellido = estudiante.primerApellido.ToUpper();
                estudiante.segundoApellido = estudiante.segundoApellido.ToUpper();
                estudiante.direccionDomicilio = estudiante.direccionDomicilio.ToUpper();

                _db.Estudiante.Add(estudiante);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(estudiante);
        }

        // GET: Estudiante/Editar/5
        public IActionResult Editar(int? Id)
        {
            if (Id == null || Id == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var obj = _db.Estudiante.Find(Id);

            if (obj == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(obj);
        }

        // POST: Estudiante/Editar/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Editar(Estudiante estudiante)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Convertir a mayúsculas antes de actualizar
                estudiante.primerNombre = estudiante.primerNombre.ToUpper();
                estudiante.segundoNombre = estudiante.segundoNombre.ToUpper();
                estudiante.primerApellido = estudiante.primerApellido.ToUpper();
                estudiante.segundoApellido = estudiante.segundoApellido.ToUpper();
                estudiante.direccionDomicilio = estudiante.direccionDomicilio.ToUpper();

                _db.Estudiante.Update(estudiante);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(estudiante);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Eliminar(int Id)
        {
            var estudiante = _db.Estudiante.Find(Id);
            if (estudiante == null)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false });
            }

            _db.Estudiante.Remove(estudiante);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
    }
}
```

**tengo la vista crear:**

```
    @model WebEscuelas.Models.Estudiante


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Crear";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<form method="post" asp-action="Crear">
    <div class="border p-3">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <h2 class="text-info pl-3">Nuevo Estudiante</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cold-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="primerNombre" class="form-label">Primer Nombre</label>
                    <input asp-for="primerNombre" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="primerNombre" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cold-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="segundoNombre" class="form-label">Segundo Nombre</label>
                    <input asp-for="segundoNombre" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="segundoNombre" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cold-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="primerApellido" class="form-label">Primer Apellido</label>
                    <input asp-for="primerApellido" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="primerApellido" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cold-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="segundoApellido" class="form-label">Segundo Apellido</label>
                    <input asp-for="segundoApellido" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="segundoApellido" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cold-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="fechaNacimiento" class="form-label">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                    <input asp-for="fechaNacimiento" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="fechaNacimiento" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cold-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="direccionDomicilio" class="form-label">Dirección de Domicilio</label>
                    <input asp-for="direccionDomicilio" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="direccionDomicilio" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cold-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="telefono" class="form-label">Teléfono</label>
                    <input asp-for="telefono" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="telefono" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crear Nuevo</button>
                <a asp-controller="Estudiante" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success">Regresar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts {
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}
```

**y tengo este otro modelo:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebEscuelas.Models
{
    public class Curso
    {
        [Key]
        public int cursoId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre del Curso")]
        public string nombreCurso { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    }
}
```

> Tengo el problema al crear una lista desplegable con viewbag, pues al momento de dar guardar en la vista crear no guarda nada y se queda en la vista del formulario, ya intente varias opciones, pero no se cual sea el problema, me gustaria con su amplia experiencia su ayuda. Lo que deseo en si es que en la vista Crear pueda seleccionar ya sea con un DropdownList o una lista despegable el curso, sin que este lo duplique, pues tambien tuve ese problema ya que el curso lo llenare desde otro controlador con sus respectivas vistas.

Comment: Cada estudiante tiene UN y solo un curso asignado????

Comment: Si exacto por el momento así funciona la aplicación